# IOException while requesting key: Invalid device key response while using Google SignIn

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-signin

I am developing an android app that uses the user's Google Drive to backup a couple of files. The picture below shows that it was working, the API had 43 requests up to that moment.

[image: API requests]

Everything was working until a few days ago, and now I can't get past the Goole SignIn screen.

I've read some other posts saying that probably the API Key registered on the developer console was different from the key from my keystore, but I've checked everything more than once and everything seems to be right. I really don't know where else to look.

This is the SignIn code:

```
private void requestSignIn() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Requesting sign-in");

        GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions =
                new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                        .requestEmail()
                        .requestScopes(new Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE))
                        .build();
        client = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, signInOptions);
        if (client.getSignInIntent() == null) {
            // The result of the sign-in Intent is handled in onActivityResult.
            startActivityForResult(client.getSignInIntent(), REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN);
        }
    }
```

And here, on onActivityResult

```
case REQUEST_CODE_DOWNLOAD_BACKUP:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && resultData != null) {
                    handleSignInResult(resultData);
                    if (driveBackupService != null) {
                        driveBackupService.restoreBackup(this);
                    }
                }
                break;
```

The resultCode that I'm receiving is 0 (which is RESULT_CANCELLED) and it should be -1 (RESULT_OK)

The SHA-1 key that is registered on the developer console does belong to the key that I'm using to sign my app so I really don't know who else to blame here.